# File History not working on RAID-5 disks

Tags: windows-10, raid, volume-shadow-copy, file-history

I have a single hard disk along with a RAID-5 configured across 3 other disks. 
On Windows 7 I had shadow copies enabled and it worked great.

After moving to Windows 10 I realized that File History was turned off. Once I tried to enable File History I could not do it on the RAID drives, only on the single disk.

Can I somehow enable File History on RAID-5 disks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've inherently answered this in my question [Configuring Windows 8/8.1/10 File History via command line](https://superuser.com/questions/1044050/configuring-windows-8-8-1-10-file-history-via-command-line)

In short, create new shared folder, only allow access to yourself, and make file history to crate backups on "network location". Reference it via `"\\127.0.0.1\File History$"` or `"\\localhost\File History$"` something, so even if you change Hostname, your backups will still work (if you put $ to end of share name, it's considered hidden, and Explorer won't show it when you or someone else browsing network; it can be listed with other software though, so don't rely on obscurity, and instead set up permissions to only allow access yourself)

Comment: Thanks @LogicDaemon that is a great workaround to access the feature!