# Exclude specific folder in automated File History setup

Tags: windows, file-history

I'm trying to enable the File History functionality in my organization. I used an application written by Ben N and [his script](https://superuser.com/a/1289407/). However, I would like to add exclusions for specific folders to it. Is there an option to do that with this app?

Comment: APK?  Android package?

Comment: You will need to be able to debug and author vb.net to figure this out.  His code is 100% vb.net.

Comment: I've added a comment with your question to the original.

Answer (score 2):

Adding an exclusion requires a call to the [`IFhConfigMgr::AddRemoveExcludeRule`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fhcfg/nf-fhcfg-ifhconfigmgr-addremoveexcluderule) function. To exclude a specific folder, add this code to your script after the paragraph mentioning `ProvisionAndSetNewTarget`:

```
newslot native addRemoveExcludeRule
copyslot addRemoveExcludeRule = vtbl field 6

// fh->AddRemoveExcludeRule(TRUE, FH_FOLDER, "C:\Users\User\Documents\Excluded")
call funcat addRemoveExcludeRule /return uint (slotdata fhPtr, int 1, int 0, bstr "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Excluded")
```

Change the path in the last line there (not just the `//` one, which is just an explanatory comment) to the one you want to exclude. Backslashes must be doubled due to escaping. To exclude multiple folders, add additional `call funcat addRemoveExcludeRule` statements with different paths. Do not duplicate the `newslot` or `copyslot` statements.

To exclude a standard folder/library rather than specifying a specific user profile path, the code is a little different. You'll need the GUID of the standard folder, which you can obtain from [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid). Put it (without curly braces) inside the quotes after an asterisk. For example, this excludes the Downloads folder:

```
// fh->AddRemoveExcludeRule(TRUE, FH_LIBRARY, "*374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B")
call funcat addRemoveExcludeRule /return uint (slotdata fhPtr, int 1, int 1, bstr "*374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B")
```

To exclude a user-specific path that isn't a standard folder or library, use environment variable expansion (after the statements that set up the `addRemoveExcludeRule` slot):

```
allocslot lpwstr userPath: 260 chars
newslot bstr userPathBstr

// userPath = ExpandEnvironmentStringsW("%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Excluded", userPath, MAX_PATH - 1)
call kernel32.dll!ExpandEnvironmentStringsW /return uint (lpwstr "%USERPROFILE%\\Documents\\Excluded", slotdata userPath, int 259)
// userPathBstr = SysAllocString(userPath)
call oleaut32.dll!SysAllocString /into userPathBstr (slotdata userPath)
// fh->AddRemoveExcludeRule(TRUE, FH_FOLDER, userPathBstr)
call funcat addRemoveExcludeRule /return uint (slotdata fhPtr, int 1, int 0, slotdata userPathBstr)
```

To set the path, change the text inside the quotes in the `ExpandEnvironmentStringsW` call statement. Unlike the other functions called here, that one returns a nonzero value when successful. To exclude multiple folders, duplicate the three call statements, but not the `allocslot` and `newslot` statements.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have one more question, is it possible to put the name of the user logged in to the path into the path, I would like to run the script using GPO so that the user does not have to perform any actions.

Comment: Yes, I added some code that adds a user-specific exclusion by incorporating the `USERPROFILE` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's great. You are my man :)

Comment: @JanuszTestowy You're welcome, glad I could help! If this solved the problem, you can click the check mark next to the post to let other users know it's the answer.